# Get Payment Information from In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I need to get the user billing address and full name, is it possible to get such information after the user finishes an In-App Purchase or do I need to  request it from the user itself?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get such information from the in-app purchase. Apple is very strict on sharing personal data of users.

Your only option would be to ask users to provide these voluntarily. Although to be honest I would be very reluctant to share such info myself. Why would an app developer need my private address?